# The word *X* means Y: Should Y be in italics, quotes, or neither?

Tags: quotation-marks, italics

Assume I'm already using the convention that a word is cited using italics.

Then which of the below should I use?

1. The word *kitten* means *young cat*.
2. The word *kitten* means "young cat".
3. The word *kitten* means young cat.

Would there be any difference if we add the indefinite article *a*?

4. The word *kitten* means a *young cat*.
5. The word *kitten* means a "young cat".
6. The word *kitten* means a young cat.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a matter of choice.

Merriam-Webster in their entry for [pedantic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pedantic) uses italics and quotes

> The word *didactic* generally means "designed to teach,"

And similarly with a Latin word under [rebus](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rebus):

> In Latin, the word *rebus* means "by things"; *rebus* is a form of the Latin word *res*, which means "thing."

The [BBC's Learn English](https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/features/6-minute-english_2024/ep-240321) website uses bold and no further punctuation for the definition

> the word **accessible** means enabling someone with a disability the opportunity to engage in the same interactions and enjoy the same experiences as people without a disability.

The Canadian government page on [values and ethics of public service](https://www.canada.ca/en/treasury-board-secretariat/services/values-ethics/code/what-is-ethics.html) uses quotes twice

> Derived from the Greek word “ethos”, which means “way of living”, ethics is a branch of philosophy that is concerned with human conduct

[This page](https://pursuit.unimelb.edu.au/articles/i-don-t-think-that-word-means-what-you-think-it-means) from the University of Melbourne's journal *Pursuit* also uses quotes twice, but their style guide evidently prefers single quotes:

> Ask any millennial and they will tell you that ‘cray’ actually means ‘crazy’.

In summary, for the first term it's a good idea to use something to set it off, but the choice is yours. For the second term (the definition), if you have a longer definition or several long definitions it's possibly neater not to use any punctuation, but quotation marks are also common. It seems logical to use different punctuation for the term and its definition, but that's not a hard-and-fast rule, and using the same punctuation for both can be perfectly clear.

Just be consistent.

Comment: I’m not entirely convinced the BBC example is equivalent – it’s expounding on what a term entails, rather than giving a dictionary-like definition. For dictionary-like definitions, I would always use italics coupled with quotes (albeit single, not double), but I wouldn’t use quotes in the BBC example either. It’s akin to things like, “Being vegan means doing your best to avoid negatively impacting animals”, where I doubt most people would even consider adding quotes/italics/bold.